# Why is this projection wrong?

Tags: 3d, geometry, computer-vision, projective-geometry

I am tring to figure out why a 3D cube doesn't project in the right place in the image.

I start with the camera at origin and the cube centered at `(0,0,1)`:

[image: front]

Then I create a 3D rotation `R` of 45 degrees around the Y axis:

```
(0.707106781, 0, 0.707106781,
0, 1, 0,
-0.707106781, 0, 0.707106781)
```

And I set the camera to use rotation `R^-1`, with a translation of `R * (0,0,1)` (these are camera to world transformations). The camera should have rotated 45 degrees CCW around the cube (I can confirm I have `0.707106781` translation on x and z).

At this point, I would expect to see the cube with the same scale, still centered, and with one of the edges right in the middle of the image. But this is what I get:

[image: side-45]

The procedure I use to project a 3d point `X` is (pseudo code):

- bring into camera coordinates: `Xc = R^-1 * X - R^1 * translation`
- transform into image coordinates: `x = Xc * focal length / Xc.z + principal point`

I have read the theory from various sources and it seems I am following the rules.

This is just artificial data, so not sure if focal length and principal point can have any effect on it? What am I doing wrong? Why is the cube not centered?

Comment: It's not clear. You said you applied a rotation to the camera and didn't say about a cube. For me it seems that you rotated a camera only - that's why the cube is not centered.

Comment: Hey @nikitablack, it was my rotation about the cube that was wrong.

Comment: So you want to rotate a cube and also a camera around the cube, right? For this you need several steps: 1) rotate a cube, that is in [0, 0, 1] position around Y axis - `cube * inv(T) * R * T`. 2) rotate a camera, that is in [0, 0, 0] around Y axis around the point [0, 0, 1] - `camera * T * R * inv(T)`